# how to use unix libraries in visual studio 2008

Tags: c, visual-studio-2008, unix

I have c code that is using unix libraries and in linking ihave the following error:

error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "double _*cdecl dlamch*(char *)" (?dlamch_@@YANPAD@Z) referenced in function "double __cdecl Num_dlamch_primme(char *)" (?Num_dlamch_primme@@YANPAD@Z) 
 s iwant away to use the unix libraries in visual studio 2008

Comment: The link error is saying you are writing C++ code, not C.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure dmlach.c is included in your project.